# How can I configure Word to automatically shift all other numbers when I change/add a number?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Microsoft Word document with numbered references. Reference numbers point to some figure, as it is typical in patent application. [E.g.](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20220138425A1/en):

> FIG. 1 shows an example of a system for natural language processing according to aspects of the present disclosure. The example shown includes user **100**, user device **105**, acronym definition network **110**, cloud **155**, and database **160**. In some embodiments, acronym definition network **110** includes input sequence encoder **115**, long form encoder **120**, scoring component **125**, long form selection component **130**, sample collection component **135**, training component **140**, processor unit **145**, and memory unit **150**. In some embodiments, the components and functions of the acronym definition network **110** are located on the user device **105**.
>
> Fig. 1 (cropped, see full image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEHBD.png)):
>
> [image]

In case I have to change add one number, e.g. 100 (adding a new 100 box in the figure), how can I configure Word to automatically shift all other numbers (old 100 becomes 105, 105 becomes 110, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to configure Microsoft Word to automatically shift all other numbers when one's change/add a number. There is no built-in feature implementing that functionality.